# pandas for loop interpolate

Tags: pandas, loops, csv, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate data for 7 indicators for 218 countries. I've got my for loop to work, but I'm having issues exporting my results to a .csv. Currently, my dataframe 'interpolated' only holds the interpolated data for the last country.

```
for i in df['Country']:
   country_interp= df[df['Country'] == i]
   upsampled = country_interp.resample('YS') 
   interpolated=upsampled.interpolate(method='linear', limit_area='inside')


Year         Country  Equiped_Actually_Irr    ...     Equiped_Ai        Ai
1992-01-01  Zimbabwe                   NaN    ...            NaN  0.056710
1993-01-01  Zimbabwe                   NaN    ...            NaN  0.056304
1994-01-01  Zimbabwe                   NaN    ...            NaN  0.055898
1995-01-01  Zimbabwe                   NaN    ...            NaN  0.055492
1996-01-01  Zimbabwe                   NaN    ...            NaN  0.055085
1997-01-01  Zimbabwe                   NaN    ...            NaN  0.054679
1998-01-01  Zimbabwe                   NaN    ...            NaN  0.054273
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a dataframe outside the loop, and then append/concat the newly generated dataframe to the one outside.

Try:

```
interpolate = pd.DataFrame()
for i in df['Country']:
   country_interp= df[df['Country'] == i]
   upsampled = country_interp.resample('YS') 
   interpolated=upsampled.interpolate(method='linear', limit_area='inside')
   interpolate = pd.concat(['interpolate', 'interpolated'], 0 , sort = False)
```

You may get an error/warning related to the sorting. If that is the case, you can add
columns = [] inside pd.DataFrame()

Comment: I'm getting the following error when i run the code: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'str'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid.

Comment: Are you sure interpolated is a datafrane?

Comment: yea, it's listing it as a dataframe